# $|(f, Tf)| \leq (f, |T|f)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $H$ be a separable and complex Hilbelt space.
If $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$, then is it true that $|(f, Tf)| \leq (f, |T|f)$ for all $f \in H$ ?

Observation.
If $H = L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $T_g f:=gf$ with $g \in L^\infty$, the above statement is true because
$$
|(f, T_g f)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|^2 |g(x)| dx = (f, |T_g|f).
$$
Note that $|T_g| = \sqrt{(T_g)^* T_g} = \sqrt{T_{\overline{g}} T_g} = \sqrt{T_{|g|^2}} = T_{|g|}$.

Comment: What is $Q?$ It is never used.

Comment: Can you please contestualize? What is $Q$ and what is $B(H)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited. @IgorRivin

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited. @DavideTrono

Comment: I am not very good at English, so please forgive me if there are any grammatical errors or rude expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $H={\mathbb C}^2$, and
$$
  T= \pmatrix{0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0}.
  $$
Then
$$
  |T| =
  (T^*T)^{1/2} =
  \left(\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0} \pmatrix{0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0}\right)^{1/2} =
  \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0}.
  $$
With $f = (z,w)$, we then have
$$
  \langle f,Tf\rangle  =   \langle (z, w),(0,z )\rangle  = \bar w z,
  $$
while
$$
  \langle f,|T|f\rangle  =   \langle (z, w),(z,0 )\rangle  = |z|^2.
  $$
The assertion being made thus becomes
$$
  |\bar wz|\leq  |z|^2,
  $$
which obviously does not always hold.

On the other hand,  in case $T$ is normal,  then the answer is yes and the proof is essentially that given by the OP,
observing that the spectral Theorem implies that every normal operator is conjugate to  a multiplication operator on an
$L^2$ space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this corresponds to  a (known) characterization of singular value decomposition as a trace maximization problem (this was certainly known to von Neumann). In finite dimension this is definitely true, in infinite dimension obvious for unitary and self-adjoint case, not 100% certain in general.